# How to check if one person is in gamemode 2 in minecraft 1.13 snapshots

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I am coding a minecraft game in command blocks, which involves the last person standing being the winner. I have made it that once a player dies, they change into gamemode 3 automatically. I am using a scoreboard that counts deaths to switch the gamemode.

My question to you is: Is there a way to detect if there is only one person in gamemode 2, and if this is true, make it enable a second command block that finishes the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean *adventure* (game mode 2) or *spectator* (game mode 3)? Your question is ambiguous

`@p[m=spectator]`
or
`@p[m=sp]`
or
`@p[m=3]`

I figured this out by looking at this documentation page:

https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Target_selectors